# recibir array en php

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito llevar un array a php para poder insertarlo en una tabla que esta en mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde `Javascript` lo estoy enviando asi

```
var table = $('#tblGrid').tableToJSON({
            ignoreColumns: [5]
        });
        JSON.stringify(table)
        table.splice(0, 1);
        var newParametros = table;
        $.ajax({
            url: "sendTophp/insertarParametros.php",
            data: { newParametros: newParametros },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (param) {
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Ha ocurrido al consultar los parametros.")
                console.log(err.responseText)
            }
        });
```

Pero no se como recibirlo en `php` para poder insertarlo en una tabla.

alguien me puede ayudar indicando como lo puedo pasar a `php`

Comment: Debes recibirlo por medio de la variable $_POST, es decir algo como esto.

$data = $_POST['table'];

Comment: var_dump($_POST['newParametros'])¿? try to $aux = json_decode($_POST['newParametros'],true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo recibes en **PHP** asi:

```
$newParametros = $_POST['newParametros'];
```

Prueba y nos comentas